# leaflet draw large number of icon marker

Tags: leaflet

i was use leaflet.js to draw about 10000 icon markers,because it is icon marker,so i cannot use circleMarker. I find a leaflet plugin [Leaflet.Canvas-Markers](https://github.com/eJuke/Leaflet.Canvas-Markers),it can help me draw 10000 icon markers fast, but this plugin caused the click event to fail.
This is my code

```
var ciLayer = L.canvasIconLayer({}).addTo(leafletMap)
    var icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'StructWell.png',
    iconSize: [20, 18],
    iconAnchor: [10, 9]
    });
    function markerClickHandler (e) {
        console.log(e)
        console.log()
    }
    let markers = []
    SiteList.results.forEach((site, i) => {
        var marker = L.marker([site.latitude, site.longitude], {icon: icon, title: JSON.stringify(site)})
        marker.on('click', markerClickHandler)
        // ciLayer.addMarker(marker)
        markers.push(marker);
    })
    ciLayer.addLayers(markers);
```

function markerClickHandler do not work when i click the marker.
was I do some bug,or are there any more solutions. The key is large number of icon markers with click event.
thanks

Comment: why you call `ciLayer.addMarker(marker)` and then `ciLayer.addLayers(markers);`?

Comment: sorry I do a mistake，code `ciLayer.addMarker(marker)` is a test, but I remove this code, click event also not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listener should be added like below:

```
 ciLayer.addOnClickListener(function (e,data) {
      console.log(data)
 });
```

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([59.9578,30.2987], 10);
    var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      preferCanvas: true
    }).addTo(map);

    var ciLayer = L.canvasIconLayer({}).addTo(map);

    ciLayer.addOnClickListener(function (e,data) {
    console.log(data[0].data.mydata)
    });
    

    var icon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/marker.png',
      iconSize: [20, 18],
      iconAnchor: [10, 9]
    });

  var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      var marker = L.marker([58.5578 + Math.random()*1.8, 29.0087 + Math.random()*3.6], {icon: icon}).bindPopup("I Am "+i);
      marker.mydata="I Am "+i
    markers.push(marker);
    }
  ciLayer.addLayers(markers);
```

```css
.map{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-canvas-marker@0.2.0"></script>
  
  <div class="map" id="map"></div>
```

You can check examples provided by  Leaflet.Canvas-Markers.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: wow, it works, thank you very much. And why event handler param data is an array, I console.log it, it has two items, and they look like same.

Comment: @freddie.wang param data contains whole information of marker which includes all marker properties and other information. It does not have only two items, it contains default options plus user defined data.